# updating numeric value with decimal in Sql server Query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to update the table

Query:

```
update um 
set ProForOccupancy = t.Occupancy 
from #Temp_UnitMix um 
join ##TempOccupency t on um.PropertyId = t.PropertyId
```

Table vlues are like this :

```
ProFormaOccupancy(int)  Occupancy(float)
     0                 0.95
     0                 0.95
     0                 0.95
     0                 0.95
```

When I am trying to update nothing is updating .. Any suggestions please ..

Comment: Try changing the update to a select and check what gets returned to make sure your join is correct

Comment: No @Spock, it is because SQL is trying to put a float, into an int. 0.95 is converted to 0.

Comment: I missed the data types.... That would do it.

Answer (score 1):

If you run this

```
SELECT CAST(0.95 AS Int)
```

You will see that the value of that is 0. That is what your update is doing, because of the different data types.

Question : Should ProFormaOccupancy be a decimal or float? In that case your table definition needs to change with something the following:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_UnitMix (
-- ... (your other columns here)
ProFormaOccupancy float

)
```

Comment: In the definition of your table, instead of ProForOccupancy int, it needs to be ProForOccupancy decimal(18,2) or ProForOccupancy  float.

Comment: Change that to float, and you will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed  my temp table structure to float . it worked .. Thank you All for your replies..